# null pointer exception for contextWrapper.getResources()? when using custom listener

Tags: java, android, multithreading, observer-pattern

getting a strange null pointer exception for a common type of custom listener that i have implemented before without any problems.

a crash will happen if i put any code in the callback method that communicates with the main user interface thread of the activity.  if i put any code inside this method that does not touch the user interface thread then there is no crash.  it does not make sense because all the code in this class runs on the UI thread and does not need to use a handler or runonui method.

how do i fix this problem?

from the logcat:

```
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at 
android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:92)
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at StartActivity.onResultReturned(StartActivity.java:124)
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at jp.co.forever.tankinspectionsystem.Synchronizer.sendInt(Synchronizer.java:215)
09-30 10:55:15.360: E/AndroidRuntime(2207):     at 
jp.co.forever.tankinspectionsystem.Synchronizer$SendOutMsgAndPack$2.run(Synchronizer.java:162)
```

code for the listener in the StartActivity class, this is utility class that does not extend activity, and all the code here runs in a new thread run method separate from the UI thread

in class variables declarations

```
 public OnResultReturnedListener listener;
```

in oncreate

```
 listener = new StartActivity();
```

listener is an interface as a nested subclass in this activity class

```
 public interface OnResultReturnedListener {
public void  onResultReturned(int result);
 }
```

code in the other class that implements the listener, all code runs on UI main thread, no additional thread are created

```
 public class StartActivity extends Activity
 implements Synchronizer.OnResultReturnedListener {

 // method onResultReturned is override for custom listerner class
 // OnResultReturnedListener interface inside of the Synchronizer class

    @Override
public void onResultReturned(int result) {

    // toast like this or any other method that touched the
    // UI thread will result in a crash
Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "value returned "
    + result , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    // putting the Toast in a handler will not help, still results in crash
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "value returned "
                    + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });

    //adding a handler.post to the other class, Synchronizer,
    // that the method call comes from
    // will not help and still causes crashes, for example
    //handler.post(new Runnable() {
    //@Override
    //public void run() {
    //fileTransferStatus = 1;
    //        listener.onResultReturned(fileTransferStatus);
    //   }
    //});

    // this statement will not cause crash
    int x = 13;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I believe the problem is in listener = new StartActivity(). You have created activivty manually that's why it doesn't have attached context and unable to interact with ui thread.

Comment: The way you put code it is hard to follow complete execution path.

Comment: that looks like the cause,  how do i fix this?  if i can't instantiate new StartActivity() like a java class when in android

Comment: Pass StartActivity reference to your Synchronizer.

Comment: YES!!!!!!  it works now. that is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is in listener = new StartActivity(). You have created activity manually that's why it doesn't have attached context and unable to interact with ui thread. You can pass StartActivity reference to your Synchronizer.

Comment: that is correct, i fixed it by passing StartActivity.this in the parameter to the other activity and instantiated listener passing that as the value into the listener variable like this, listener = (OnResultReturnedListener) activity, thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that passing one activity to another is the best choiсe) But I can not say for sure without code.

Comment: in this case i don't think memory leaks are a problem.  if that is a problem then i will use WeakReference<Activity>